# How do I build SQLite3 from command line?

Tags: macos, sqlite, command-line, build, makefile

I'm kind of rusty at building software from the command line. whenever i've had to do it I just follow directions..so i don't have to tools to troubleshoot when something goes wrong...as it has today. I've run into a problem trying to build SQLite3 on a PowerPC Mac running OS X 10.5.8 (Leopard).

here are the "instructions" i'm following:

```
$ curl -O http://sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3.6.21.tar.gz
$ tar xzf sqlite-amalgamation-3.6.21.tar.gz
$ cd sqlite-3.6.421
$ ./configure –prefix=/usr/local
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

And here's what I'm doing...

```
$ pwd
/usr/local/src
$ curl -O http://sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3.7.3.zip
$ unzip sqlite-amalgamation-3.7.3.zip
$ ls -l
total 9096
-rw-r--r--@ 1 elvis  admin    82346 Oct  7 19:37 shell.c
-rw-r--r--  1 elvis  admin  1217170 Nov 20 11:47 sqlite-amalgamation-3_7_3.zip
-rw-r--r--@ 1 elvis  admin  4245940 Oct  7 19:36 sqlite3.c
-rw-r--r--@ 1 elvis  admin     3961 Oct  7 19:37 sqlite3.def
-rw-r--r--@ 1 elvis  admin   291339 Oct  7 19:37 sqlite3.h
-rw-r--r--@ 1 elvis  admin    20686 Oct  7 19:37 sqlite3ext.h
$ ./configure –prefix=/usr/local
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Am I missing a **configure** file?  Do I have the wrong source? I grabbed the zip version because I couldn't find the tarball (though admittedly didn't look too hard).

**How do I build sqlite3 so it installs in /usr/local?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must cd into the new in-tarred folder, then run ./configure. Also, use tar. It's better.

So: cd sqlit (hit tab)
./config...

Comment: i couldn't find the tarball because the version number naming was slightly different `http://sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3.7.3.tar.gz` as opposed to `3_7_3.zip`. Anyway, got it. And it installed painlessly... thanks!